# What's the cause of MS Outlook starts flashing?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

One of my our computers experiences the flashing problem seen in **[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTFilAc3UuE)**. It occurs approximately every other day. A fix is to restart Outlook, but this is not a satisfactory solution. The problem is limited to Outlook alone and not any other MSOffice application.

Specifications:
Windows 10
MSOffice 2016
OS and MSOffice are up to date

Comment: Have you reinstalled/updated the graphics drivers already?

Comment: Yes, the graphics drivers are up-to-date.

Comment: Try a repair install of Office.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2768648/display-issues-in-office-client-applications), you may experience this symptom if you have a video configuration on your computer that is incompatible with the Office feature set that is responsible for displaying the application and for animations in the application.

Try to follow the suggestions in the article to see whether it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still facing this issue, I think it is related to sorting the Outlook folders.

You go to “Folder” tab and click on “Show all folders A to Z.”

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

#### Outlook uses hardware graphics acceleration. In case of problems, disable it.

menu **File** > **Options** > tab **Advanced** > check **Disable hardware graphics acceleration**

[image]

From my experience, rendering problems can be random, occuring even on a computer where Outlook worked without such issues for long time. Sources of problems are: update of Windows • update of Office • update of graphics driver. It is often not worth rolling back any of these updates. Just tick the above option and check whether the problem disappeared. (Potentially also restart Outlook.) The impact of disabled hardware graphics acceleration is generally unnoticeable.